# Building model using caret package in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, model, r-caret

I have a challenge and need help. I am doing my first data science project , the challenge arouse when building the model. am following up a tutorial on edureka (https://www.edureka.co/blog/data-science-projects/), where could the error arise from

```
set.seed(30162)
trnctrl <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10) 
boostfit <- train(incomelevel ~ age + educationnum + relationship + workclass +
                    occupation + relationship + maritalstatus +
                    hoursperweek + capitalgain + capitalloss +
                    race + nativecountry,
                  trcontrol = trnctrl,
                  method="gbm", 
                  data=trainset, 
                  verbose=FALSE)
```

I had checked for any missing values in the incomelevel variable:

```
table(complete.cases(trainset$incomelevel))
 TRUE 
31978
```

error:

```
Error in na.fail.default(list(incomelevel = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, : missing values in object
``
```

glimpse(trainset)

```
Observations: 31,978
Variables: 14
$ age           <int> 39, 50, 38, 53, 28, 37, 49, 52, 31, 42, 37, 30, 23, 32, 34, 25, 32, 38, 43, 40, 54, 35, 43, 59,...
$ workclass     <fct> State-gov, Self-emp-not-inc, Private, Private, Private, Private, Private, Self-emp-not-inc, Pri...
$ education     <fct> Bachelors, Bachelors, HS-grad, 11th, Bachelors, Masters, 9th, HS-grad, Masters, Bachelors, Some...
$ educationnum  <int> 13, 13, 9, 7, 13, 14, 5, 9, 14, 13, 10, 13, 13, 12, 4, 9, 9, 7, 14, 16, 9, 5, 7, 9, 13, 9, 10, ...
$ maritalstatus <fct> Never-married, Married-civ-spouse, Divorced, Married-civ-spouse, Married-civ-spouse, Married-ci...
$ occupation    <fct> Adm-clerical, Exec-managerial, Handlers-cleaners, Handlers-cleaners, Prof-specialty, Exec-manag...
$ relationship  <fct> Not-in-family, Husband, Not-in-family, Husband, Wife, Wife, Not-in-family, Husband, Not-in-fami...
$ race          <fct> White, White, White, Black, Black, White, Black, White, White, White, Black, Asian-Pac-Islander...
$ sex           <fct> Male, Male, Male, Male, Female, Female, Female, Male, Female, Male, Male, Male, Female, Male, M...
$ capitalgain   <int> 2174, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14084, 5178, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
$ capitalloss   <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2042, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
$ hoursperweek  <int> 40, 13, 40, 40, 40, 40, 16, 45, 50, 40, 80, 40, 30, 50, 45, 35, 40, 50, 45, 60, 20, 40, 40, 40,...
$ nativecountry <fct> United-States, United-States, United-States, United-States, Cuba, United-States, Jamaica, Unite...
$ incomelevel   <fct> <=50K, <=50K, <=50K, <=50K, <=50K, <=50K, <=50K, >50K, >50K, >50K, >50K, >50K, <=50K, <=50K, <=...
```

Comment: As per the error message, Check for the missing values in `incomelevel` field. Also, check  data type of the field. It should be factor.

Comment: I had checked and it indicated no missing values

Comment: what about datatype?

Comment: it is a factor ,do I need to change the ```method="gbm",``` or what is you advise

Comment: could you share output of the following: `glimpse(trainset) `

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this question a second time, I believe the data needs to be Pre-Processed a bit more. What needs to be done is [One-Hot-Encoding](https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/). Looking at the error message it claims not to have integer values for `incomelevel`. Since you only showed a small snippet of data all we can see is

```
incomelevel   <fct> <=50K, >50K, ...
```

This leads me to think that the `<=` and `>` signs are messing things up also. Your model requires integers as it says above. Try writing a small bit of code to transform `incomelevel <=50K, >50K, ...` to

```
| Row No. | <=50K | >50K | more(?) |
| ------: |-----: |----: |-------: |
|       1 |     0 |    1 |       0 |
etc...
```

Then append your new table to your current data and delete `income`.

It looks like you may need to do this with all your factors if you find problems.

IMHO, it is better to transform string data to integers, 0,1's only.